# An ArrayList is not being updated properly

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

So I am doing a homework assignment and for one of the methods we write we are supposed to create an iterable object that has all the potential 3x3 boards that result in shifting 0.  The boards are added to an ArrayList to be iterated later.  With a board of:

```
0 1 3 
4 2 5 
7 8 6
```

I should be getting

```
4 1 3 
0 2 5 
7 8 6
```

and

```
1 0 3 
4 2 5 
7 8 6,
```

but I am getting

```
1 0 3 
4 2 5 
7 8 6
```

and

```
1 0 3 
4 2 5 
7 8 6.
```

I have tried using stack and push as well, but it ends up with the same result.  I have absolutely no Idea what is causing it so can someone give me a suggestion?

```
public class Board {
private int[][] myTiles;
private int N;

// create a board from an n-by-n array of tiles,
// where tiles[row][col] = tile at (row, col)
public Board(int[][] tiles){
    myTiles = tiles;
    N = myTiles[0].length;

private static void exch(int[][] comp, int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2){
    int copy = comp[row1][col1];
    comp[row1][col1]=comp[row2][col2];
    comp[row2][col2]=copy;
}

public Iterable<Board> neighbors(){
    ArrayList<Board> boards = new ArrayList<>();
    int[][] comp = myTiles;
    int row=0;
    int col=0;

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            if(myTiles[i][j]==0){
                row=i;
                col=j;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("row: " + row + " col: " + col);
    System.out.println(" ");
    if(row>0){
        exch(comp,row,col,row-1,col);
        boards.add(new Board(comp));
        exch(comp,row,col,row-1,col);
    }
    if(row<(N-1)){
        exch(comp,row,col,row+1,col);
        boards.add(new Board(comp));
        exch(comp,row,col,row+1,col);
    }
    if(col>0){
        exch(comp,row,col,row,col-1);
        boards.add(new Board(comp));
        exch(comp,row,col,row,col-1);
    }
    if(col<(N-1)){
        exch(comp,row,col,row,col+1);
        boards.add(new Board(comp));

    }
    for (Board b : boards) {
        System.out.println((b.toString());
    }
    return boards;
}
```

Comment: Define "shifting zero."

Answer (score 3):

Your boards are fake copies. All of them have the same underlying `myTiles` because the constructor says:

```
myTiles = tiles;
```

Unlike C++, this only creates a reference to the same `tiles` array.

Make a deep copy using a loop to iterate over the values and you should be OK.